# How do I perform type casting in an *ngFor for an array of mixed types in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two objects (`DeviceA` and `DeviceB`) with the same parent class (`Device`)

```
interface Device {
  shared: string
}

interface DeviceA extends Device {
  attributeA: string[]
}

interface DeviceB extends Device {
  attributeB: number
}
```

In my component, I have an array that contains instances of `DeviceA` and `DeviceB`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  devices: (DeviceA | DeviceB)[] = [];
}
```

How do I iterate through this array in the template? My desired outcome is something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let device of devices">
  <div *ngIf="'attributeA' in device">
    <span *ngFor="let str of device.attributeA">{{ str }}</span>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="'attributeB' in device">
    <span>{{ device.attributeB }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want to call either attributeA or attributeB depending on the type. But compiling fails because `Property 'attributeA' does not exist on type 'DeviceA | DeviceB'`

How do I properly perform typecasting here?

Comment: Your type is wrong and should be `devices: (DeviceA | DeviceB)[] = []`. Then you can perform narrowing with `"attributeA" in device` instead of using `instanceof`.

Comment: @vr. How exactly do I perform narrowing? I've tried to use `<div *ngIf="'attributeA' in device">`  instead of `<div *ngIf="device instanceof DeviceA">` and changed the type of devices to `devices: (DeviceA | DeviceB)[] = []`, but now the compiler error I get is `Property 'attributeA' does not exist on type 'DeviceA | DeviceB'`

Comment: Hm, I don't really know how Angular templates work with TypeScript. Using `in` works "outside" of templates. Can you update your post with your attempt using `in`?

Comment: @vr. I've just updated the post. And yes, my problem is with type casting correctly within the template..

Comment: why not just add a type for each interface and then check `*ngIf="device.type==1"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is a superset of JavaScript, all interfaces will be lost after compiled becoming Objects, so you cannot infer class types from interfaces using instanceOf. You have two options, continuing using interfaces, and infer type from the params, or use classes with `instanceOf`.
To uses this type of operations at the HTML, Angular make the uses of pipes, check the examples bellow, and the [code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtr54e?file=src/is-device-type.pipe.ts).

***At the stackblitz, the code is showing how to cast the type in HTML.***

### First form, using interfaces

Create a pipe in Angular

**device-type.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'isDeviceType'
})
export class IsDeviceTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: DeviceA|DeviceB, expect: 'a' | 'b'): boolean {
        if (expect==='a') return !!(value as DeviceA).attributeA;
        return !!(value as DeviceB).attributeB;
    }
}
```

### Second form, using classes

Create a pipe in Angular

**device-type.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'isDeviceType'
})
export class IsDeviceTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: DeviceA|DeviceB, expect: 'a' | 'b'): boolean {
        if (expect==='a') return value instanceOf DeviceA;
        return value instanceOf DeviceB;
    }
}
```

### and on your HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let device of devices">
  <div *ngIf="device | isDeviceType:'a'">
    <span *ngFor="let str of device.attributeA">{{ str }}</span>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="device | isDeviceType:'b'">
    <span>{{ device.attributeB }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Check the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtr54e?file=src/is-device-type.pipe.ts